# iOS text not updating instantly - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have the `viewDidLoad` function here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    titletxt.text = GlobVar.getTitle()
    infotxt.text = GlobVar.getInfo()
    loctxt.text = GlobVar.getLoc()
```

where `titletxt`, `infotxt` and `loctxt` are the labels/text boxes in that particular view. GlobVar is just a class containing variables with information.

For some odd reason when this `viewDidLoad` function runs, it seems to update the text field but it is not shown until after I refresh the view (i.e- exit the window and enter again.)

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Move the code to `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Do I create this function myself? It is not available as an override function

Comment: It is a standard UIViewController method you can override `viewWillAppear(animated:Bool)`

Comment: Never mind it is, I seem to get `Expected , separator` on `animated: true` though. No idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`viewDidLoad()`** is only called once, when the `UIView` is created.

As mentioned above you should put this code in **`viewWillAppear`**, or even **`viewDidAppear`**.

These methods are both part of [**`UIViewController`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:), and will be called automatically by the system for you at obvious times (when the view will/did appear).